# XSLT 2.0 template matching - strip all attributes which are not in the desired namespace

Tags: xml, xslt, xpath, xml-namespaces, xml-attribute

I have an XML with differently namespaced attributes - it's basicly a kind of extended XHTML. I want to dump all the non-xhtml namespaced attributes.

Examplary source XML:

```
<html>
  <body>
    <p class="test" xy:foo="true">blah</p>
  </body>
</html>
```

At the moment, i have the following XSLT template:

```
<xsl:template match="@*">
    <xsl:choose>
        <xsl:when test='namespace-uri()="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"'><xsl:copy-of select="."/></xsl:when>
        <xsl:otherwise></xsl:otherwise>
    </xsl:choose>
</xsl:template>
```

Desired output XML:

```
<html>
  <body>
    <p class="test">blah</p>
  </body>
</html>
```

But it doesn't seem to match, because i get an output XML completely without attributes. I have the feeling that `namespace-uri()` does not work as expected. Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The attributes on XHTML elements (like your `class` one) are attributes in no namespace, not in the XHTML namespace. So use

```
<xsl:template match="@*[namespace-uri() != '']"/>
```

plus the identity transformation template.